# jquery - add/remove class of just one input field, not all of them using $(this)

Tags: jquery, this

So now I have it change the BG color, but on every field with that class name.

How do I correctly add to the class to just the one being checked by the onchange click and not all that have the same name ?

Trying to post this and the page is asking for more details, but I do not know what else I can add to explain what I am after apart from the first two lines at the top of this post !  So I'll just explain here that this entire paragraph is just to fill the post with something else to get it to post !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script><?php // this line nust be first before the jquery-ui.js ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<style>
.eventGroup { float: left; padding: 0 3em 3em 0; }
.eventGroup .n, .eventGroup .p { width: 20em; }
.eventGroup .s, .eventGroup .e { float: left; width: 10em; }
.addMore { padding-right: 1.5em; }
.formError { background-color: #FF4747; }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".addMore").click(function(){
                var fieldHTML = '<div class="eventGroup">'+$(".eventGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';    $('body').find('.eventGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
            });//add more fields group

        $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){  $(this).parents(".eventGroup").remove();    });//remove fields group
    });

function checkFormOK(field) {
//alert(    field + ' ' + $('input:text').val());
// When a field is changed, check if it is empty, if so, mark as red.
    if (field == 'n') { // process the names.
        if ($('input:text').val().length == 0) {
//          alert('empty');
            $('.n').addClass('formError');      //      does not change the BG color.
        } else { $('.n').removeClass('formError');
        }
    }
//  if (field == 'p') { // process the prices.
//  }

//  When a date field is changed, check if the dates entered overlap any of the other dates in other groups.
//  if (field == 's' || field == 'e') { // process the dates.
//  }

}

/*
// When a date field is changed, check if the dates entered overlap any of the other dates in other groups.
//var startDates = document.getElementsByClassName('s');
//var endDates = document.getElementsByClassName('e');
//  for (let s = 0; s < startEndDates.length; s++) {
//      for (let e = 0; e < startEndDates.length; e++) {
            //console.log(groups[i].value);

            if (s1 != s2) { // do not check a group with itself !, skip to next one.
                if (document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s1).value >= document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s2).value &&
                document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s1).value < document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s2).value) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s1).className = 'se formError'; document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s2).className = 'se formError';
                        document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s1).className = 'se formError'; document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s2).className = 'se formError';
                }
            }

//      }
//  } 
*/
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="editDatePrices.php">
        <div class="centerText">
            <div class="eventGroup">
                <input class="n" onchange="checkFormOK('n')" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter name" value="Event 1"><br>
                <input class="p" onchange="checkFormOK('p')" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals" value="123"><br>
                <input class="s" onchange="checkFormOK('s')" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="2023-08-13">
                <input class="e" onchange="checkFormOK('e')" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value="2023-08-14">
                <div class="clearFloat"></div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
            </div>
            <div class="eventGroup">
                <input class="n" onchange="checkFormOK('n')" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter name" value="Event 1"><br>
                <input class="p" onchange="checkFormOK('p')" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals" value="123"><br>
                <input class="s" onchange="checkFormOK('s')" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="2023-08-13">
                <input class="e" onchange="checkFormOK('e')" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value="2023-08-14">
                <div class="clearFloat"></div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
            </div>
        <div class="eventGroup" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div class="clearFloat"></div>
        </div>
    <br><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addMore">Add more</a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="checkFormOK()">
</form>

            <!-- copy of input fields group -->
            <div class="eventGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
                <input class="n" onchange="checkFormOK('n')" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name" value=""><br>
                <input class="p" onchange="checkFormOK('p')" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" value=""><br>
                <input class="s" onchange="checkFormOK('s')" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="">
                <input class="e" onchange="checkFormOK('e')" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value=""><br>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a><br>
            </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass extra parameter when on change event fire in your function like `checkFormOK('n',$(this))` . And based upon that parameter  add and remove your class.

Examplee:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <?php // this line nust be first before the jquery-ui.js ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


  <style>
    .eventGroup {
      float: left;
      padding: 0 3em 3em 0;
    }
    
    .eventGroup .n,
    .eventGroup .p {
      width: 20em;
    }
    
    .eventGroup .s,
    .eventGroup .e {
      float: left;
      width: 10em;
    }
    
    .addMore {
      padding-right: 1.5em;
    }
    
    .formError {
      background-color: #FF4747;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".addMore").click(function() {
        var fieldHTML = '<div class="eventGroup">' + $(".eventGroupCopy").html() + '</div>';
        $('body').find('.eventGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
      }); //add more fields group

      $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).parents(".eventGroup").remove();
      }); //remove fields group
    });

    function checkFormOK(field, _this) {
      //alert(field);
      //alert(    field + ' ' + $('input:text').val());
      // When a field is changed, check if it is empty, if so, mark as red.
      if (field == 'n') { // process the names.
        if (_this.val().length == 0) {
          //alert('empty');
          _this.addClass('formError'); //      does not change the BG color.
        } else {
          _this.removeClass('formError');
        }
      }
      //  if (field == 'p') { // process the prices.
      //  }

      //  When a date field is changed, check if the dates entered overlap any of the other dates in other groups.
      //  if (field == 's' || field == 'e') { // process the dates.
      //  }

    }

    /*
    // When a date field is changed, check if the dates entered overlap any of the other dates in other groups.
    //var startDates = document.getElementsByClassName('s');
    //var endDates = document.getElementsByClassName('e');
    //  for (let s = 0; s < startEndDates.length; s++) {
    //      for (let e = 0; e < startEndDates.length; e++) {
                //console.log(groups[i].value);

                if (s1 != s2) { // do not check a group with itself !, skip to next one.
                    if (document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s1).value >= document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s2).value &&
                    document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s1).value < document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s2).value) {
                            document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s1).className = 'se formError'; document.getElementsByClassName('s' + s2).className = 'se formError';
                            document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s1).className = 'se formError'; document.getElementsByClassName('e' + s2).className = 'se formError';
                    }
                }

    //      }
    //  } 
    */
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <form method="post" action="editDatePrices.php">
    <div class="centerText">
      <div class="eventGroup">
        <input class="n" onchange="checkFormOK('n' ,$(this))" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter name" value="Event 1"><br>
        <input class="p" onchange="checkFormOK('p',$(this))" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals" value="123"><br>
        <input class="s" onchange="checkFormOK('s',$(this))" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="2023-08-13">
        <input class="e" onchange="checkFormOK('e',$(this))" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value="2023-08-14">
        <div class="clearFloat"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
      </div>
      <div class="eventGroup">
        <input class="n" onchange="checkFormOK('n',$(this))" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter name" value="Event 1"><br>
        <input class="p" onchange="checkFormOK('p',$(this))" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price i.e.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;no decimals" value="123"><br>
        <input class="s" onchange="checkFormOK('s',$(this))" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="2023-08-13">
        <input class="e" onchange="checkFormOK('e',$(this))" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value="2023-08-14">
        <div class="clearFloat"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
      </div>
      <div class="eventGroup" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    </div>
    <br><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addMore">Add more</a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="checkFormOK()">
  </form>

  <!-- copy of input fields group -->
  <div class="eventGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
    <input class="n" onchange="checkFormOK('n',$(this))" type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name" value=""><br>
    <input class="p" onchange="checkFormOK('p',$(this))" type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price" value=""><br>
    <input class="s" onchange="checkFormOK('s',$(this))" type="date" name="eventStart[]" value="">
    <input class="e" onchange="checkFormOK('e',$(this))" type="date" name="eventEnd[]" value=""><br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a><br>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have done a complete rewrite of the code to do away with IDs.  Found an issue when new groups added that would not be found as the numbers sequencing is out.  Will be posting a new question with the same issue still